# Cygwin Serial Port permission denied error

Tags: linux, cygwin

I have installed Cygwin in Windows 7. I am trying to access serial port from Cygwin via /dev/ttyS0 interface. But everytime I access, it gives permission denied error.
    '$ stty raw < /dev/ttyS0'
    -bash: /dev/ttyS0: Permission denied

When I check the permission of this device:
    '$ ls -l /dev/ttyS0'
    'crw-rw-rw- 1 user1 Domain Users 117, 0 Nov  3 14:31 /dev/ttyS0'

This shows that I have rights. Also, I have read somewhere that ttyS0 is COM1 of Windows.
I have also checked with administrator rights explicitly with Runas and with 'cygstart --action=runas command'.
I have googled it but did'nt find right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If the rights are proper it should work.This error can also happen if another software has grabbed the ttyS0 even before cygwin is started. There can also be some race condition where another application grabs it ahead of Cygwin.

Comment: There is no other application running at the time when Cygwin is accessing the Serial port. Also we have checked that serial port works perfectly with other applications.